# How to copy a folder over SSH with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, ssh, build, scp, gulp

I have been experimenting with gulp lately, and have had a lot of success, but now I am stumped.

I have gulp building everything, and I want to upload a folder afterwards. I have created a `deploy` task for this using `gulp-scp2`:

```
gulp.task('deploy', ['clean', 'build'], function() {
    var privateKeyPath = getUserHome() + '/.ssh/id_rsa';

    gulp.src('public/dist')
        .pipe(scp({
            host: 'myhost',
            username: 'user',
            dest: '/home/user/test',
            agent: process.env['SSH_AUTH_SOCK'],
            agentForward: true,
            watch: function(client) {
                client.on('write', function(o) {
                    console.log('write %s', o.destination);
                });
            }
        })).on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error: Content should be buffer or file descriptor
```

How can I copy a folder over SSH using gulp?

Comment: It doesn't look like `gulp-scp2` is a valid gulp plugin, since it's not listed on the [gulp website](http://gulpjs.com/plugins/).  Have you tried [gulp-sftp](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-sftp/)? It looks like a better designed solution, and should accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Why dont you use a repository and push there whatever you want ? I think is the best way to deploy files on production.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did end up finding a solution by leveraging the node `scp2` library:

```
scpClient = require('scp2');

gulp.task('scp', [], function (cb) {
    scpClient.scp('local_folder', {
        "host": "remote_host",
        "port": "remote_port",
        "username": "username_on_remote",
        "path": "/path/on/remote",
        "agent": process.env["SSH_AUTH_SOCK"],
        "agentForward": true
    }, cb)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer, i ended using a node version directly, this one will work in gulp 4+ way:

First install the lib (Be sure of installing locally in the project, the global version doesnt work for using in gulp file):

```
 npm install scp2
```

Then in the gulp file:

```
 var scpClient = require('scp2');


 function deploySCP2(){
    return scpClient.scp(paths.buildAll, {
       "host": "host",
       "username": "username",
       "password": "password",
       "path": "path"
    }, function(err) {  })
 }
```

This will work rightaway.